# How to prevent Illustrator from converting text to path when saving project as SVG?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, svg

When saving an Illustrator file which contains some text as SVG, the text is converted to outlines. How can this be avoided? It is possible in Inkscape.

[image]

Comment: Have you already converted the font to outlines before you have tried to save it as svg (Can you still edit the text in illustrator)?
My svg options dialog looks slightly different and produces the desired output. Are you using the latest version of illustrator?

Comment: I did not convert it. How can I restore the defaults without reinstalling?

Comment: I reinstalled illustrator but it's still not working(when I uninstalled it I chose to delete preferences). Your svg options dialog look different because I clicked "more options". I am using 2015 verison.

Comment: Which font do you use?

Comment: Tested it with the same font as used in your example.
Noticed that some individual characters were transformed in position when exported to svg, maybe older versions of Illustrator could not handle that correctly and convert them to outlines.
Have you tried using another font?

Comment: Yes, I tried: Adobe Caslon Pro, Arial, Comic Sans MS, Open Sans.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the language to English and now it's working!  (and I still can to write in non-English language)    (:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem for more than a year now, where Illustrator seems to randomly convert some text to path when exporting to SVG. (There are some patterns in this random behaviour though, it often happens when texts contain sub/superscript or when they are multiline, separated by soft returns).

It seems to be solved by using the *Save As* dialog instead of *the Export for Screens* dialog. When Saving As, the '*more options*' you can choose for *All Glyphs* under *Fonts > Subsetting*. Now all text is saved as text, and not sometimes as outlines.